# How do I convert a JSON array into individual values to insert into my SQL table?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

Here's a snippet of the json data:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "State",
    "Honey producing colonies",
    "Yield per colony",
    "Production",
    "Stocks December 15",
    "Average price per pound",
    "Value of production",
    "Year"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "AL",
      "41",
      "20",
      "820",
      "33",
      "0.54",
      "443",
      "1989"
    ],
    [
      "AZ",
      "78",
      "45",
      "3510",
      "1158",
      "0.55",
      "1931",
      "1989"
    ]
]
}
```

And I've created a table here:

```
CREATE TABLE HoneyTbl (
     "State" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Honey producing colonies" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Yield per colony" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Production" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Stocks December 15" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Average price per pound" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Value of production" VARCHAR(MAX),
     "Year" VARCHAR(MAX),
)
```

And now I'm trying to extract the json data of rows here:

```
Declare @Json varchar(max)
SELECT @Json = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Temp\honey.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@Json, '$.rows')
```

But I'm stuck as it's outputting as an array like this:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|key| value                                                            |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0 | [   "AL", "41", "20", "820", "33", "0.54", "443", "1989"   ]     |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I select individual values from that array and insert them into my table?  I need each one to be under a different column. (Need row values to line up with columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use `OPENJSON`'s [`WITH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#with_clause-1) clause to scope in and map each row.

```sql
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rows')  
  WITH (
     [State] VARCHAR(MAX) '$[0]',
     HoneyProducingColonies VARCHAR(MAX) '$[1]',
     YieldPerColony VARCHAR(MAX) '$[2]',
     Production VARCHAR(MAX) '$[3]',
     Stocks VARCHAR(MAX) '$[4]',
     AveragePricePerPund VARCHAR(MAX) '$[5]',
     ValueOfProduction VARCHAR(MAX) '$[6]',
     Year VARCHAR(MAX) '$[7]'
  )
```

Comment: Okay thank you, that worked, except it's not what I want, but I'm on the right track here. I need all those row values to be in the same row together, not each in their own individual row. Is there a way to put them each in a row together, just separate values.

Comment: You should be able to use `JSON_VALUE` to pick them out of the array. Just make sure each array has the same dimensions and format

Comment: @Mariot Updated my answer with the relevant SQL

Comment: Thank you @WardenUnleashed unfortunately it's giving me an error:

JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '[' is found at position 2.

What I'm having trouble with is that when I try to pull data from $.rows if I use $.rows[1] that'll give me the 2nd set of array values not the second value within the array.

Comment: @Mariot I fixed my answer to map it correctly. Also, the snippet of JSON in your question is missing  a closing array.

Comment: Thank you! This works as well. Also updated json code with closing array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample using `JSON_VALUE()`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=10c0da075e3f8b4af05efdb8831d8876)**

```
Select [key]
      ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[3]')
      ,Pos5 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[4]')
      ,Pos6 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[5]')
      ,Pos7 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[6]')
      ,Pos8 = JSON_VALUE(value,'$[7]')
 From  OpenJson(@json,'$.rows')
```

**Results**

```
key Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8
0   AL      41      20      820     33      0.54    443     1989
1   AZ      78      45      3510    1158    0.55    1931    1989
```